# How to set a number as block or spam in Ring central if a user press 0

Tags: ringcentral

I want to set a number as spam if a RingCentral user gets an incoming call and he dials 0 form dial-pad It should set the number as Spam and from the next time that number should be in the block list.
Is there any way to do this using API and Webhooks in RingCentral.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any API to set a spam number. Looks like this is a good feature request.